# Qual è il significato di "patire" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Rideva, parlando, mostrava i denti grandi, cavallini. «Non vi conviene riprendervelo, nevvero?» Allargava la sua risata fino alla cordialità; diceva: «Non ci pensi, non ci pensi. Il bambino per ora sta bene dove sta». Aveva i capelli tutti bianchi, camminava lentamente, respirava a fatica, si appoggiava al bastoncino nero col manico d’argento che raffigurava un cane. La nonna rispondeva, umilmente: «È il suo signor marito che non ce lo vuol restituire. Lo fa forse **patire**, il bambino, perché noi si possa toglierlo di forza?». «Oh, non lo fa **patire**, non c’è pericolo, non lo fa **patire**...» rispondeva la signora, ridendo: rideva fino a farsi venire la tosse.

Il bambino di cui si parla è il fratello minore dell'autore, che era stato preso a casa dei signori quando la loro madre morì pochi giorni dopo il parto.

Mi potreste spiegare il significato di "patire" in questo brano? Ho cercato questo verbo in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capirne il senso nel passaggio sopra citato. Quello che mi sembra strano è questo pronome "lo" che accompagna l'espressione "far patire": mi chiedo: far patire che cosa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/patire1/) la parte che più si addice a questo senso è:

> **c.** Con uso assoluto, sostenere una sofferenza (per dolori fisici o morali, in seguito a privazioni, stenti, offese, umiliazioni, ecc.): *Gesù Cristo patì sotto Ponzio Pilato*; *ha patito molto nella sua vita*; *siamo in questo mondo per patire*; *quanto mi ha fatto patire quest’ulcera!*; *amateli perché hanno patito, perché patiscono* (Manzoni); *ha finito di patire*, espressione di commiserazione per chi è morto, con allusione alle sofferenze di una malattia lunga e dolorosa o di una vita poco felice.

Quindi *soffrire*, *subire privazioni* o simili. Con *fare* preposto significa naturalmente infliggere sofferenza o privazioni.

Come spiegare *lo*? È il medesimo pronome di *non lo fa andare*, *lo tiene acceso* e simili.

Comment: Se il senso è "fa soffrire al bambino", il pronome non dovrebbe essere "gli" invece di "lo"? Cioè, non dovrebbe essere "gli fa patire"?

Comment: @Charo No, perché? Ci vorrebbe *gli* se fosse “non gli fa patire la fame”. Ma qui il verbo *patire* è usato in modo assoluto e in questo caso il pronome è *lo*. Suppongo ci sia una spiegazione grammaticale, ma al mio orecchio è del tutto naturale.

Comment: Quindi "il bambino" è in questo caso complemento diretto?

Comment: @Charo Esattamente: “non fa patire il bambino”.

Comment: A pensarci meglio, credo che "patire" con questo senso sia intransitivo, ma la locuzione "far patire" (+ qualcuno) sia invece transitiva.

Comment: @Charo Infatti: come in “il macchinista fa partire il treno”.

Comment: ...o, in questo caso, “lo fa partire, il treno”.

Comment: Una forte indicazione che *patire* può avere questo senso transitivo è l'esistenza del participio passato [*patito*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/patito/)

Comment: @DenisNardin: È transitivo quando ha il senso menzionato nella risposta di abarisone (*patire il freddo*, per esempio), ma è intransitivo quando ha il significato spiegato in questa risposta. Ma qui stiamo parlando della locuzione "far patire qualcuno": "qualcuno" è complemento diretto di "far patire".

Answer (score 1):

Il significato di ***patire*** nel brano da te citato è ***soffrire***.

La preoccupazione è che il bambino potesse soffrire fame, freddo, sete, oppure altre privazioni in senso più generale.

Da Treccani per [patire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/patire1/):

> 2. a. Nell’uso com., provare, sentire, subire, sperimentare su sé stessi qualcosa che sia spiacevole in sé o rechi dolore, danno,
>      disagio, offesa e sim., materiale o non materiale (per lo più sinon.
>      di *soffrire*): *p. il freddo, la fame, la sete; patisco spesso il mal di
>      testa* (o, con uso intr., *di mali di testa*); *p. il martirio; p. le pene
>      dell’inferno; p. un’ingiustizia, un sopruso, una prepotenza; p.
>      mancanza, carestia, disagio di qualche cosa;* anche con soggetto di
>      cosa: *la proprietà ha patito gravi danni per l’incuria
>      dell’affittuario.*

Comment: Ma perché questo "lo"? Fa soffrire che cosa?

Comment: Lo semplicemente come pronome: non fa patire a lui (il bambino) freddo, fame, sete, etc. Viene ripetuto come rafforzativo. Si potrebbe scrivere: "Lo fa forse patire perché noi si possa toglierlo di forza?" oppure "Fa forse patire il bambino perché noi si possa toglierlo di forza? "

Comment: Ma si dice "fa patire il bambino" ("il bambino" complemento diretto) oppure "fa patire al bambino" ("al bambino" complemento di termine)?

Comment: Si dice "Fa patire **il** bambino", cioè soffrire in senso generale oppure se si vuole specificare si dice "fa patire **al** bambino freddo, fame, sete, etc."